# Syntax highlighter Not showing proper code on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, syntax, syntaxhighlighter

I just started using crayon syntax highlighter plugin in WordPress and code on the site auto update itself like `&&` changes to `&amp;&amp;`

look the image below

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you choose a proper Language as highlighted on the picture. I use Crayon Syntax Highlighter too with no problem. If still doesn't work reinstall the plugin.

[image]

Comment: I'm using C++ and it's no good. Maybe a known issue? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ampersand-character/